# MobileFirst 6.3 adapter IGNORE_COOKIES policy still sends cookies

Tags: cookies, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security, mobilefirst-adapters

We are using custom device provisioning to authenticate devices to our WebSphere Portal back-end.

We have our adapter set to connect as endUser, and the cookies policy to IGNORE_COOKIES.

But for some reason, the adapter still uses a shared Ltpa token to connect to the backend for all devices.

In this state, the user is NOT authenticated in the Worklight Server yet, so I am not sure whether the connect as endUser option will work as intended. But IGNORE_COOKIES should?

```
var input = {
    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'json',
    path : 'DeviceService/DeviceInfo/' + deviceId,
    headers : {"Authorization": "Basic " + auth},
    parameters : {
        token: token
    }
};

try {
    var result = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    return result;
} catch (e) {
    WL.Logger.error("ERROR: " + e);
    return null;
}
```

Our authenticationConfig.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tns:loginConfiguration xmlns:tns="http://www.worklight.com/auth/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
             5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
             US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
             disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp. -->
    <securityTests>
        <mobileSecurityTest name="MAPCertLogin">
            <testDeviceId provisioningType="custom" realm="MAPLoginRealm"/>
            <testAppAuthenticity/>
        </mobileSecurityTest>
    </securityTests>
    <realms>
        <realm loginModule="StrongDummy" name="SampleAppRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        </realm>
        <realm loginModule="MAPLoginModule" name="MAPLoginRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DeviceAutoProvisioningAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="validate-csr-function" value="Authenticator.validateCSR"/>
        </realm>
    </realms>
    <loginModules>
        <loginModule name="StrongDummy">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>
        <loginModule name="requireLogin">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>
        <loginModule name="MAPLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DeviceAutoProvisioningLoginModule</className>
            <parameter name="validate-certificate-function" value="Authenticator.validateCertificate"/>
        </loginModule>
    </loginModules>
</tns:loginConfiguration>
```

I can't confirm it anymore, but I am pretty sure this worked in our Worklight 6.2 environment.

What could be the reason for the ltpa token still being send?

Comment: Stijn, can you add to the question your authenticationConfig.xml file?

Comment: Thanks Idan Adar, I have added the xml to the question.

Comment: Hi Idan Adar, have you been able to reproduce the issue? I have created a test app without any security tests, and in this situation all seems to work as should, but as soon as I added the provisioning code, the server starts to use a shared ltap token. Any idea where to start to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A defect was found for this problem and a fix is available for IBM customers. Contact IBM Support for more details.

ibm.com/support

Answer (score 0):

IMHO : you should not touch the cookie policy.
The cookie policy is mainly for correct cookie parsing from Worklight to the backend HTTP server and vice versa. As side effect the cookie may be passed back to the client.
Its true that Liberty will attach an incoming HTTP request an LTPA token but it should not bother your application. It is simply added to the response cookie. The only case where Worklight server will start to validate this cookie is when using WorklightLTPAAuthenticator module. I didn't see you use it.
You use device provisioning which relies on correct WWW-authenticate headers and some JSON responses.
If you have an error with the device provisioning you should check the challenge handler in the client that handles the CSR hand shake.

Comment: Thank you taitelman for your response. But the connection between the client and worklight server is not the problem. The Challenge handler is working as intended. The worklight server is sending for each device the same ltpa token to the backend. This causes the backend server to identify each device as the same user. Therefore the content displayed is incorrect.

Comment: On 2nd thought you maybe right. I'm checking the code to understand the problem. the server doesn't ignores the cookie as expected. this probably affects Worklight v6.3 +ifix level from Dec 28th 2014 or later as well as v7.0.